# TypeError: d[("get" + method)] is not a function in reactjs while reading data from firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

When I am clicking the week button, it gives me the error:

TypeError: d[("get" + method)] is not a function
(anonymous function)
node_modules/date-arithmetic/index.js:281
  278 | })(method);
  279 | 
  280 | return function(d, val){

> 281 |   if (val === undefined)
>         | ^  282 |     return d'get' + method
>     283 | 
>     284 |   var dateOut = new Date(d)

Normally, it has to show the data according to their start and end time.

[image]
[image]

```
getReservations = () => this.db.ref('reservations');
```

---

```
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar';

const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);
const DragAndDropCalendar = withDragAndDrop(Calendar);

class CalFormBase extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            calendarInitialState,
            events: [
                {
                    allDay: true,
                    start: Date(),
                    end: Date(),
                }
            ]
        };
    }

componentDidMount() {
            this.props.firebase.getReservations().on('value', snapshot => {
            this.setState({
                events: snapshot.val(),
            });
        });
    }


render() {
        if (this.state.events) {
            return (
                <div className={'row'}>
                    <MuiThemeProvider>
                        <div className={'col-2'}>
                            Equipments:
                            <FloatingActionButton
                                mini={true}
                                className={'m-2'}
                                onClick={() => this.handleEquipments()}
                            >
                                <ContentAdd />
                            </FloatingActionButton>
                            <Sidebar
                                events={this.state.equipments}
                                onClickEvent={this.handleEquipments}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div style={{ height: 500 }} className={'col-8'}>
                            <DragAndDropCalendar
                                events={this.state.events}
                                onEventDrop={this.moveEvent}
                                resizable
                                localizer={localizer}
                                onEventResize={this.resizeEvent}
                                defaultView="month"
                                defaultDate={new Date()}
                                onSelectEvent={this.selectEvent}
                                min={minTime}
                                max={maxTime}
                                backend={false}
                            />                              
                        </div>                          
                    </MuiThemeProvider>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not related to firebase itself, but the way you are passing the data to the calendar library, Firebase Timestamp are different than javascript date objects; I would suggest trying something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
            this.props.firebase.getReservations().on('value', snapshot => {
            const data = snapshot.val()
            data['start'] = data['start'].toDate()
            data['end'] = data['end'].toDate()
            this.setState({
                events: snapshot.val(),
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: it gives me this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'toDate' of undefined

Comment: r u 100% sure that there snapshot.val() is returning something an object with start and end properties?

Comment: when I defined the data in my js file, this was working. Also, start and end properties were working too. But I am not sure if it is returning an object now